# Print the first value without knowing the key

Tags: json, jq, key-value

I have a JSON value

```
{
    "RandomKey1": "3.1.44.0",
    "Common": {
        "Services": "3.50.103.0",
        "Common": "3.50.103.0"
    }
}
```

I want to get the value of `RandomKey1`. As you may have guessed, the name of the key changes every time when I load the page, so I need to get the value of the 0th key. It is guaranteed to be at the 0th position

I was expecting at least some result with this

```
cat result.json | jq -r '.[0]'
```

but instead I get the error

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index object with number.
```

I tried the function `keys` and it is returning the keys as expected. However there is no `values` function otherwise I could have obtained the values and return only the first element

```
cat result.json | jq -r 'keys'
```

Is there any way to get the 0th value from this string when the key name is unknown ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [`first/1`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#first,last,nth(n)).

```
first(.[])
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/f94JD1_f7L)</sup>

If you at least know that the first value is always scalar, then you can discard the rest of the input to avoid exhausting memory and wasting CPU time.

```sh
$ jq --stream -n 'input[1]' file
"3.1.44.0"
```

Answer (score 2):

> I tried the function `keys`

You could use the `keys_unsorted` function like so:

```
.[keys_unsorted[0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `to_entries` function to get there!

```
jq 'to_entries|.[0].value' file.json
```

should do the trick.

From `jq` doc:

> If to_entries is passed  an  object,
> then for each k: v entry in the input, the output array includes {"key": k, "value": v}.

So after it your json will look like this:

```
[
  {
    "key": "RandomKey1",
    "value": "3.1.44.0"
  },
  {
    "key": "Common",
    "value": {
      "Services": "3.50.103.0",
      "Common": "3.50.103.0"
    }
  }
]
```

where you can find the first key and its corresponding value.